# Apache of type java.lang.string cannot be converted to JSON object

Tags: java, android

When I send a request I got this response in HTML format

> 07-08 03:27:56.447: D/log_tag2.0(2383): Out side Catch Error
>   converting result Apache Tomcat/7.0.55 - Error
>   report
>
> ## HTTP Status 405 - Request method 'POST' not supported
>
> **type**
>   Status report
>
> **message** Request method 'POST' not
>   supported
>
> **description** The specified HTTP method is
>   not allowed for the requested resource.
>
> #### Apache Tomcat/7.0.55
>
> 07-08
>   03:27:56.447: D/log_tag3(2383): Inside Catch Error parsing data
>   org.json.JSONException: Value Apache of type
>   java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject

How can i solve this problem ?

Comment: Your title and your question seems to be like two different -maybe related?- questions. You should also share the configuration/code of your problem and how do you call it.

Comment: You should show your webservice code, at least.

Answer (score 0):

1. Your question is not clear.
2. 405 is when you not have configured your webservice. Since you use tomcat, you might have not defined your service in pom.xml probably.
3. Make the post request through your browser first, to check if your server is actually working or not.